# ActiveRecord - selecting the ID of a user's most recent appointment

Tags: sql, activerecord, group-by

I have a `User` table and a list of all their appointments in an `Appointment` table. A user can book multiple appointments, so their most recent appointment might not be the same as the highest ID.

e.g. Appointment 1 is booked for July 16. Before Appointment 1 occurs, the user decides they'd also like one sooner and books Appointment 2 for July 15.

I can get the ids on a per-user basis using a loop and then combine them, but out of curiosity, I was wondering how this could be done in one single query.

Something along the lines of:

```
User.joins(:appointments).group(:id).pluck("MAX(appointments.date)")
```

This only gets the date though, and not the id of the appointment that has that date. While my question is for ActiveRecord, if anyone has a solution in something like SQL I'm sure I could find an analogous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about ActiveRecord I'm afraid, but in SQL, I would use a self join with a less than condition to achieve this. I set up some temp tables to demonstrate:

```
create table #User
(
    id int,
    fullName varchar(50)
)

create table #Appointment
(
    id int,
    userId int,
    apptDate date
)

insert into #User
values (1, 'John Smith'), (2, 'Jane Doe'), (3, 'Robert White'), (4, 'Sharon Black')

insert into #Appointment
values 
    (1, 3, '2019-08-01'),
    (2, 2, '2019-10-21'),
    (3, 1, '2019-07-16'), --John Smith Appointment 1, booked for July 16th
    (4, 4, '2019-09-28'),
    (5, 1, '2019-07-15') --John Smith Appointment 2, booked for July 15th
```

You can then run the following query to return each User and their earliest dated appointment, along with it's `id` and any other fields you want:

```
select
    u.fullName,
    a.id as EarliestAppId,
    a.apptDate as EarliestAppDate
from #User u
left join #Appointment a on u.id = a.userId
left join #Appointment earlier on u.id = earlier.userId and earlier.apptDate < a.apptDate
where earlier.id is null
```

This returns the following results, correctly identifying the earlier of John Smith's 2 appointments:

```
/------------------------------------------------\
| fullName     | EarliestAppId | EarliestAppDate |
|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
| John Smith   |       5       |    2019-07-15   |
| Jane Doe     |       2       |    2019-10-21   |
| Robert White |       1       |    2019-08-01   |
| Sharon Black |       4       |    2019-09-28   |
\------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I asked this question a year ago but didn't really get it at the time so I left it. I'm running into a similar problem now and your answer has been very helpful. One unique issue though is that my User and Appointment tables are linked by an intermediate UserAppointment table, so the left join isn't work as intended since I had to join a secondary UserAppointment that makes each row unique, so they remain even if the left join fails. Do you have any insight on how to overcome this?

Comment: Il did it working through a series of workarounds, but I will say I think this gets slower by a quadratic factor since it relies on joining the Appointment table a second time. Nonetheless I appreciate the help and learned a lot about SQL through trying to implement this